# VC++ System::ComponentModel::Container usage, and Controls variable

Tags: c++, winforms, visual-c++, components, containers

1- I've made a simple Windows Form application, and found this line generated:

```
System::ComponentModel::Container ^components;
```

and this in the destructor of the form:

```
if (components)
        {
            delete components;
        }
```

However, when I comment both of them, there's no difference at all. Could you please tell me its usage in my code and/or an example of its usage?

Thanks in advance, here's the full code.. just a very simple Form, I deleted a lot of unnecessary lines that specify the drawing of my things

```
#pragma once

namespace PC2newversion {

using namespace System;
using namespace System::ComponentModel;
using namespace System::Collections;
using namespace System::Windows::Forms;
using namespace System::Data;
using namespace System::Drawing;

/// <summary>
/// Summary for SignUp
/// </summary>
public ref class SignUp : public System::Windows::Forms::Form
{
public:
    SignUp(void)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        //
        //TODO: Add the constructor code here
        //
    }

protected:
    /// <summary>
    /// Clean up any resources being used.
    /// </summary>
    ~SignUp()
    {
        if (components)
        {
            delete components;
        }
    }
private: System::Windows::Forms::Label^  label8;
protected: 
private: System::Windows::Forms::TextBox^  textBox8;
private: System::Windows::Forms::TextBox^  textBox7;
private: System::Windows::Forms::Label^  label7;
private: System::Windows::Forms::Label^  label6;
private: System::Windows::Forms::TextBox^  textBox6;
private: System::Windows::Forms::Label^  label5;
private: System::Windows::Forms::TextBox^  textBox5;
private: System::Windows::Forms::Button^  button1;
private: System::Windows::Forms::TextBox^  textBox4;
private: System::Windows::Forms::TextBox^  textBox3;
private: System::Windows::Forms::TextBox^  textBox2;
private: System::Windows::Forms::TextBox^  textBox1;
private: System::Windows::Forms::Label^  label4;
private: System::Windows::Forms::Label^  label3;
private: System::Windows::Forms::Label^  label2;
private: System::Windows::Forms::Label^  label1;

private:
    /// <summary>
    /// Required designer variable.
    /// </summary>
    System::ComponentModel::Container ^components;

#pragma region Windows Form Designer generated code
    /// <summary>
    /// Required method for Designer support - do not modify
    /// the contents of this method with the code editor.
    /// </summary>
    void InitializeComponent(void)
    {
        this->label8 = (gcnew System::Windows::Forms::Label());
        //Deleted many unnecessary lines here

        // 
        // SignUp
        // 
        this->AutoScaleDimensions = System::Drawing::SizeF(6, 13);
        this->AutoScaleMode = System::Windows::Forms::AutoScaleMode::Font;
        this->ClientSize = System::Drawing::Size(379, 266);
        this->Controls->Add(this->label8);
        this->Controls->Add(this->textBox8);
        this->Controls->Add(this->textBox7);
        this->Controls->Add(this->label7);
        this->Controls->Add(this->label6);
        this->Controls->Add(this->textBox6);
        this->Controls->Add(this->label5);
        this->Controls->Add(this->textBox5);
        this->Controls->Add(this->button1);
        this->Controls->Add(this->textBox4);
        this->Controls->Add(this->textBox3);
        this->Controls->Add(this->textBox2);
        this->Controls->Add(this->textBox1);
        this->Controls->Add(this->label4);
        this->Controls->Add(this->label3);
        this->Controls->Add(this->label2);
        this->Controls->Add(this->label1);
        this->Name = L"SignUp";
        this->Text = L"SignUp";
        this->ResumeLayout(false);
        this->PerformLayout();

    }
#pragma endregion
};
}
```

2- In

```
this->Controls->...
```

Isn't Controls supposed to be a variable (a pointer or a handle)? Then, where's it declared?